# anchor tag in codeigniter keeps on reloading the the page when clicked

Tags: php

view code:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>projects/more_details/<?php echo $res->project_name;?>/<?php echo $res->id;?>">More Details</a>
```

controller code:

```
$project = $this->uri->segment(3);
$id = $this->uri->segment(4);
$data['visits'] = $this->projectsModel->list_visits($id);
$data['bills'] = $this->projectsModel->list_bills($id);
$data['project'] = $project_name;
$this->load->view('projects/more_details.php',$data);
```

When I click on anchor tag it keeps on reloading `more_details.php`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Anything in more_details.php that would make it reload?  If you call more_details.php directly from the browser, does it do the same thing, or only when you click the href ?

Comment: only when i click anchor tag. i think $id is the problem. when i dont pass $id, everything works fine.

Comment: At this point, I think we need to see the code of more_details.php.  It should also contain `print_r($_GET);` to know what that page received.